# How make a stage in Jenkins Pipeline that will check a URL for a specific JSON response and succeed/fail?

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am deploying a WAR using Jenkins and I want the final pipeline stage to actually hit the endpoint and check the JSON response. If it comes up *and* has the right value, then it succeeds, otherwise the build should fail.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can use `CURL` in shell script to call that URL, if you receive anything other than 200 then exit from the script with the error code `exit xxx` ie. `exit 125`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment{
        CHECK_URL = "https://stackoverflow.com"
        CMD = "curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null ${CHECK_URL}"

    }

    stages {
        stage('Stage-One') {
            steps {
                script{
                    sh "${CMD} > commandResult"
                    env.status = readFile('commandResult').trim()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage-Two') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo ${env.status}"
                    if (env.status == '200') {
                        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
                    }
                    else {
                        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please change the CMD as per your need and also the post section can be used to set the build status. Thanks!

---

Below curl is one example of printing the Jason value

```
  curl -s 'YOUR-URL' | \
        python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['VARIABLE-TOFILTER']"
```

[Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)